# C++ passing array of strings to a function

Tags: c++

So I want to pass an array of std::strings to a function. The number of std::strings in the array is predefined via preproc. directives. The whole thing should look like this:

```
#define ARRAYSIZE 3
void foo(std::string[ARRAYSIZE]);
void foo(std::string instrings[ARRAYSIZE])
{
...
}
```

Question: Can I call on the function without having to save the std::string array first to a variable, and then calling with that? So basically I want to call it with one line, like:

```
void main()
{
...
foo( std::string x[ARRAYSIZE] = {"abc","def","ghi"}  );
...
}
```

Problem is that I can't figure out the correct syntax of the function call (I'm not even sure there is one), visual studio's intellisense keeps shooting my ideas down.

Comment: Using `std::array` and `std::vector` is good for the soul.

Comment: `#define` for constants is totally unnecessary. Use `const` or `constexpr` instead.

Comment: @chris I'd say it depends on the scope. If I am to use the same array length on multiple unrelated functions, and the length must be exactly the same I'd use a define. But then again it's not exactly best practice, and this comes from a C perspective... at the end of the day, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @rath, You can use a global constant if you really need to. At least it's actually an object that obeys scoping rules and not just text being replaced.

Comment: @chris +1, the text-replace argument makes sense.

Comment: The preproc. define is not the problem, VS keeps giving me errors if I simply put 3 instead of ARRAYSIZE. The problem is that I can't define arrays of strings on the fly without getting "error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler".
std::array doesn't exist in VS, which is weird to be honest, cause I'm using VS 2013 which should compile full C++11.
As for std::vectors, I still don't know how to define one of strings on the fly :)

Comment: If you don't want to go for a container, you could use a reference to an array of defined length.

Comment: `std::array` works fine in Visual C++ 2013.  Include the `array` header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to switch to `std::vector` that can be constructed on the fly as you have mentioned in the comment to the question, this should work (works with gcc):

```
void foo(const std::vector<std::string> &stringVec)
{
}

int main()
{
    foo( std::vector<std::string>({"abc","def","ghi"}));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! :) I had to rewrite foo so it expects a vector, which means the compiler doesn't check the array's size anymore, it accepts any vector of strings, but I can just check it myself and give some horrible error message if the size is not ARRAYSIZE

Answer (score 1):

One way to pass multiple values like this {x0,x1,x2,...} would be to use std::initializer_list which was introduced in c++11. Although this way it is not possible to force a constant number of values.

```
void foo(const std::initializer_list<std::string>& input) {

}

int main() {
    foo({"abc","def","ghi"});
}
```